# Why does Swift's map function behave differently with an array of boolean values?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import SwiftUI

var arrayInt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var resultInt1 = arrayInt.map {$0}
var resultInt2 = arrayInt.map {$0 + 3}
print(resultInt1)
print(resultInt2)

var arrayString = ["a", "b", "C", "d", "e"]
var resultString1 = arrayString.map {$0}
var resultString2 = arrayString.map {$0.uppercased()}
print(resultString1)
print(resultString2)
```

> Error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: '$0' is immutable

```
var arrayBool = [true, true, true, true, true]
var resultBool1 = arrayBool.map {$0}
var resultBool2 = arrayBool.map {$0.toggle()} 
print(resultBool1)
print(resultBool2)
```

Comment: The question is why does toggle behave differently than uppercased! Try and check which methods modified the instance itself and which method returns a new instance instead.

Comment: Use a non-mutating function for Bool: `var resultBool2 = arrayBool.map {!$0}`

Comment: [Setting one bool](https://tio.run/##fVA9b8IwEN39K96YSAhRiSlShiJ16NQfgBiscKGWwgWdz4UKwV8PF0OLsnCD76z3cc@Ox9Dqchh@vMCLoMa69V2kGR5NJT0vuW2co5MSx9Az3kX8L47fJISPjvbEirrGqu87nB2s9km9Bt6hTdwgkn5xEXhLpwqfrOWDNdYuedkao2vnRggNRVxrZC7IFuMMIU3CuLh/0Ui31DlHIXSgvKz6S9z0ibW6m@a5nCjX2X1jBuM7M3Rx5n6QwFrYh5TOjvkk9aJ8CS9fw2@LqX4Ybg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$0` element inside a map is considered immutable `let`

## toggle  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/toggle())

```
 mutating func toggle()
```

Mutates the instance itself , so it gives error as `$0` is a `let`

## uppercased [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/uppercased())

```
func uppercased() -> String
```

Returns a string after processing the `$0`  , so it passes as it doesn't mutate `$0`